# Acumatica - Push Notifications for Opportunity Screen

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to implement Push Notification to Webhook, for our initial testing we used Opportunities screen. When we update any record or create new opportunities nothing is being pushed to webhook and in request profiler we observed the RowCount as 0. As per Acumatica guide lines we are not using any formulas and complex joins in GI. This is standard Acumatica GI we used in Push Notifications.

When we initially verified this it was not working, so we thought it may be because of our customizations package, so we unpublished all our package and tested again but still not working.

We are on Acumatica 2019R1 Build - 19.106.0020 (without any customization packages published). How can we fix this?

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new webhook for CROpportunites with simple GI and it is working for me.

In, Generic Inquiry I have added Estimation Date(CloseDate DB filed), when this field is modified, then the details will be triggered. Please find the screenshots for reference.

Please let me know if you still have any questions.

**Opportunites Screen**
[image]

**Push Notifications screen**
[image]

**CR Opportunites GI**

[image]

**Details we can see on Webhook Site**

[image]

Comment: Hi Naveen, when we tried in fresh instance it worked for us but not sure what is wrong without uat site, if you don't mind can you please share you email address will discuss.

Comment: Sure, I will provide you the Skype ID: naveen9960